# Using the value of a variable instead of its name for new variable declaration

Tags: java, string, variables, declaration

Suppose I've a variable in java

```
String test=new String();
```

Now i want to declare a new variable with its name equal to the value of the variable 'test'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, because the name is fix to compile time!

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that in Java, use a java.util.Map instead.

For example:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("key1", "key2");
map.put((String) map.get("key1"), "whatever");
```

Comment: Could you please exemplify the above statement.

Comment: Consider i've a string variable test='abc'. I want to create a new variable whose name should be 'abc' i.e. the name of the new variable that i want to create should be 'abc'. Could you please give the code for this?

Comment: I understood your question, but it is not possible in Java. In most of the script programming languages you can do it (Ruby, Javascript, etc) but Java does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, Java doesn't allow adding variables in reflection
however, you can use `Map<String,Object>` to achieve it.

```
String test = new String();
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Object myNewObject = new Object();
map.put(test,myNewObject);
```

now, you seek your new objects by:

```
map.get(test);
```

amit

Comment: Consider i've a string variable test='abc'. I want to create a new variable whose name should be 'abc' i.e. the name of the new variable that i want to create should be 'abc'. Could you please give the code for this?

Comment: assume you have a String test as described, an object named aNewObject (which is the value for the new Object 'named' abc):
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put(test,aNewObject);
you may now get your new object by:
map.get(test); or map.get("abc");